# Jquery - tabs - collapsilbe - animated transition

Tags: jquery, tabs

Having trouble getting a certain set of requirements to work together.

Starting with the base JQuery UI demo:
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#collapsible
Setting Collapsible to True allows the tabs to close when clicking the active tabheader
That works fine.....

We need the tabs to be closed on load, so added Active; False
That works ok.....

Now, we would like to add a transition so that when tabs are changed, it isn't a fast jarring change, but a nice smooth transition.

What is happening, is that when choosing a different tab, the active tab is closing all the way while the other opens.

Is there a way for the panels to animate just to the size of the newly selected panel without closing all the way.

I realize that what is actually happening is the active panel is closing, and another (separate) panel is opening.

so the JQuery UI demo adjustment approach we are using, may not be the best approach.

Looking for advice and suggestions to achieve the above description.

thanks
-Dave

Comment: Can you add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you've tried?

Comment: Hey, @DaveBar, did you end up solving this?  If you have, you can help out the 601 internet searchers who've viewed this thread by posting your solution or hitting the ✓ on one an answer that helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an event for when the selected tab changes using

```
$("#tabs").tabs({activate:function(){...}});
```

and `$("#tabs")` needs an absolute height so it can be animated.

```
$( "#tabs" ).height($(ui.newPanel||ui.panel).height()+83);
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/QHgmL/) for a working example.